# A quote supposedly from Gustave Flaubert

Tags: quote-source, french-language, latin-language

So, do some of you happen to know, did Gustave Flaubert really say *Pulchritudo vitae in vico, ea videtur solummodo a poetis, ea non videtur a hominibus in vicis.* or anything like that? If so, where?

If he did not say that, do you know where that quote actually originates?

Comment: For those of us who don't speak Latin, could you include at least an English (maybe even a French) translation of this phrase?

Comment: @Zenix, "Ea non videtur a hominibus in vicis." probably means "People in villages don't see it.",  don't you think?

Comment: Is it the correct translation *"The beauty of the life in the village, it would seem to be fulfilled only by the poets, It does not seem to come from the men in the villages"*?

Comment: @Zenix, I don't know, I guess it is. Is that actually proper Latin?

Comment: Where did you find this quote? And why is Flaubert supposedly writing in Latin, not French?

Comment: @PeterShor, I found it in my Latin textbook, Hereditas Linguae Latinae.

Comment: Flaubert may have said "il n'y a pas de particule de vie qu'il n'ait pas de poésie à l'intérieur de celui-ci". In English, the quote is "there is not a particle of life which does not bear poetry within it", and it's found many places on the internet. The French translation I can only find in one book, and it's possible it's a retranslation of the English into French.

Comment: @PeterShor, Where? What does that mean?

Comment: If the Latin quote means "Only poets see beauty in the life of the village; those who live there don't," it expresses a vaguely similar idea. I couldn't find anything closer in Flaubert's *Complete Works*, but it's possible that the quote comes from his notebooks (*carnets*), which have been published.

Comment: Oops ... "à l'intérieur de celle-ci". I got the gender of *particule* wrong when I transcribed it for the comment above.

Comment: @PeterShor, OK, I get it, Gustave Flaubert probably didn't say that or anything like that, and it's very hard to tell where that quote originates.